# Nuxt app freezing while using nested routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In the index (home page), if I click a button and navigate to:

```
http://localhost:3000/browse/songs/new
```

it freezes the browser and there is no response with blank white page!

However, if I enter manually this url, it works.

**my pages directory structure:**

```
--browse
    --songs
        --new
            index.vue

browse.vue
index.vue
```

I found an issue on github but it doesn't helped me!

[App freezes while using nuxt-link and nested routes with redirect](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2896)

Comment: create a reproduction on codesandbox or github. Its impossible to tell without code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is actually related to the issue on github you linked to.

If I understand you correctly your pages directory is like so:

```
|-browse (folder)
|  |-songs (folder)
|    |-new (folder)
|      index.vue (file)
|-browse.vue (file)
|-index.vue (file)
```

This would be causing confusion for nuxt because you basically have two different things trying to be the same thing, your 'browse' folder and your 'browse' file.

You should try it like this:

```
|-browse (folder)
|  |index.vue (file) //this replaces your browse.vue file and can be found at http://localhost:3000/browse
|  |-songs (folder)
|    |-new (folder)
|      index.vue (file) //this can be found at http://localhost:3000/browse/songs/new
|-index.vue (file)
```

**If the above** breaks a nuxt-child arrangement the following seems to work.

```
|-browse (folder)
|  |index.vue (file) 
|  |-songs (folder)
|    |-index.vue 
|    |-new (folder)
|      index.vue (file) 
|-browse.vue
|-index.vue (file)
```

Because of the nesting of the routes, to find the `<nuxt-child/>` of each you need to include it in an index.vue at each level. The file can contain simply this:

```
//browse-index.vue && browse-songs-index.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-child/>
  </div>
</template>
```

but it keeps the child chain alive.

Comment: but with this structure, i have problem. in |-browse , index.vue i have two components that should load in sub pages. in browse index.vue i have <nuxt-child/> but it doesn't render those component in songs/new/index.vue. what should i do?

Comment: Yes that would be a problem. I think your folders are too nested to work properly with nuxt-child, and probably causes your original problem. For nuxt-child to work the child should be only one layer deep, as far as I know. If you need that structure you could use a regular component structure instead. OR post some code for @Aldarund to look at, he's the master of this sort of thing.

Comment: what is `regular component structure`?

Comment: I mean just a normal component. So if you want /browse/songs/new to look like /browse but with some additional content, have a component that is used in browse-index.vue and in browse-songs-new-index.vue and add the additional content (new songs I guess) after the component. Thought of something else... I'll edit answer.

Comment: its freezing again with new structure (browse.vue)

Comment: I can't recreate the freezing. What browser are you using? Might be something else in browse.vue. Maybe show code.

Comment: this is my browse.vue :    `<Tabs :items="tabs"/>

    <v-container fluid grid-list-lg>
      <Slider :items="slides"/>
    </v-container>
<nuxt-child />`

Comment: if i want to have this structure what should i do?

`|-browse (folder)
|  |-songs (folder)
|    |-index.vue 
|    |-new (folder)
|      index.vue (file) 
|-index.vue (file)`

is it right?

i want to make `songs index.vue` the parent component. i have `<nuxt-child/>` and some components  in `songs index.vue` but it doesn't render in `songs new index.vue`

Comment: The structure I put in the answer, after the "If the above..." works for me and I can have content at each child level that displays fine. If that doesn't work for you it might be you have an older version of nuxt. Mine is 2.5.1. Check package.json and see what yours is.

Comment: "nuxt": "^2.4.0",

is it possible to update my project?

Comment: It is but 2.4 should be fine. There's no major change from there. If you want to update you can. There's release notes [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/release-notes). Basically just change the version in package.json to "nuxt": "^2.6.1", delete the package-lock.json file and npm install.

Comment: i upgraded to 2.5.1, and i decided to change the structure like this: [img](http://uupload.ir/files/4s66_capture.png). but still ! my app freezing! and this is  [songs.vue component](http://uupload.ir/files/7rxg_capture.png).

Comment: my structure is like this: `-| pages/
---| parent/
------| child.vue
---| parent.vue`
but i don't know why my app freezed!

Comment: i found it! my problem is about middleware. `export default (context) => {
  context.redirect('/browse/songs/new');
}` i deleted it, but i wan't to if user navigate to browse/songs, automatically redirects to browse/songs/new. what should i do?

Comment: If you always want to redirect you could just have this in /browse/songs-index.vue: `created() { this.$router.push('/browse/songs/new') }`. Otherwise try your middleware like this: `export default ({redirect}) => { return redirect('/browse/songs/new') }`. You might just need to return the redirect.